# ngrx Types of parameters 'source$' and 'source' are incompatible

Tags: angular, rxjs

Segui el tutorial de ngrx y da error el proyecto lo subí a github

```
En otro post las respuestas que dieron sobre el mismo error no dan una solucion 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66820549/angular-in-strict-mode-with-ngrx

books$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectBooks))
```

Finalmente pude ejecutar el código del tutorial Walkthrough tuve que modificar el tipado de los objetos en forma distinta a los del tutorial con lo cual finalmente se ejecuto subí los cambios a mi repositorio en github con lo cual si se ejecuta el proyecto github.com/nestdanchia/ngrxAngularStrictMode
por ejemplo en
`BookCollectionComponent --> books!:Book[]  BookComponent-->   books$!: Observable<Book[] bookCollection$:Observable<Book[]> |       undefined>`
en BookComponent-->
[tutorial oficial de ngrx da error con Angular 12 en strict mode](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/walkthrough) 
Los tipos de parámetros 'source$' y 'source' no son compatibles.
[proyecto con el error](https://github.com/nestdanchia/ngrxAngularStrictMode)

Proyecto con Angular 12 y ngrx segui la guia del mismo en la
pagina de ngrx

```js
interface AppState {
   
    books: Book[]  ;
    collection: string[]  ;
  }
interface Book {
    id: string;
    volumeInfo: {
      title: string;
      authors: Array<string>;
    };
}
const selectBooks = createSelector(
  (state: AppState) => state.books,
  (books: Array<Book>) => books
);

 books$= this.store.pipe(select(selectBooks));
 
.......................................
No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "(source$: Observable<AppState>) => Observable<Book[]>" al parámetro de tipo "OperatorFunction<object, Book[]>".
  Los tipos de parámetros 'source$' y 'source' no son compatibles.
    El tipo 'Observable<object>' no se puede asignar al tipo 'Observable<AppState>'.
      Al tipo "{}" le faltan las propiedades siguientes del tipo "AppState": books, collectionts(2345)
(alias) const selectBooks: MemoizedSelector<AppState, Book[], DefaultProjectorFn<Book[]>>
import selectBooks
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: La idea es que tu pregunta pueda usarse en el futuro sin depender de que tu cuenta en github siga existiendo, borres o no el repositorio, etc. Así pues, revisa los enlaces y mira cómo preguntar. Esto incluye poner un ejemplo mínimo verificable aquí, EN tu pregunta.

Comment: ahora modifique store.d.ts para que la clase Store tenga un tipo any con lo cual pude ejecutar el codigo del componente book list pero para el componente book collection aunque no me da error en VSC al ejecutar dice que el tipo Book o undefine no es asignable al tipo Book las modificaciones las subi a  github

Comment: Finalmente pude ejecutar el código del tutorial Walkthrough tuve que modificar el tipado de los pbjetos en forma distinta a los del tutorial con lo cual finalmente se ejecuto subi  los cambios a mi repositorio en github con lo cual si se ejecuta el proyecto https://github.com/nestdanchia/ngrxAngularStrictMode